# ReactJS - TypeError: setPage is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in ReactJS. Just after finishing a course on the basics of React and Redux. I have started a new Udemy course entitled "React Data Visualization - Build a Cryptocurrency Dashboard."

I am facing a problem in lecture 12. When I run `yarn start` on Git Bash terminal on Visual Studio Code, I see this page:

[image]

When I click on **Dashboard**, I get this error:

```
TypeError: setPage is not a function
onClick
C:/Users/Shawn/Desktop/cryptodash/cryptodash/src/App/AppBar.js:31
  28 | {({page, setPage}) => (
  29 | <ControlButtonElem 
  30 |     active={page === name}
> 31 |     onClick={()=>setPage(name)}
     | ^  32 | > 
  33 |     {toProperCase(name)}
  34 | </ControlButtonElem>
```

Here are my codes in `AppBar.js` under `App` folder:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled, {css} from 'styled-components';
import {AppContext} from './AppProvider';

const Logo = styled.div`
    font-size: 1.5em;
`

const Bar = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 180px auto 100px 100px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
`
const ControlButtonElem = styled.div`
    cursor: pointer;
    ${props => props.active && css`
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 60px #03ff03;
    `}
`

function toProperCase(lower){
    return lower.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lower.substr(1)
}

function ControlButton({name}){
    return(
        <AppContext.Consumer>
            {({page, setPage}) => (
            <ControlButtonElem 
                active={page === name}
                onClick={()=>setPage(name)}
            > 
                {toProperCase(name)}
            </ControlButtonElem>
            )}
        </AppContext.Consumer>
    ) 
}

export default function(){
    return (
    <Bar>
        <Logo>Cryptodash</Logo>
        <div/>
        <ControlButton active name="dashboard" />
        <ControlButton name="settings" />
    </Bar>
    )
}
```

Here are my codes in `AppProvider.js` under `App` folder:

```
import React from 'react';

export const AppContext = React.createContext();

export class AppProvider extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            page: 'settings',
            setpage: this.setPage
        }
    }
    setPage = page => this.setState({page});
    render(){
        return(
            <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </AppContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

Here are my codes in `index.js` under `App` folder:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
```

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo here

```
setpage: this.setPage
```

I think it Should be

```
setPage: this.setPage
```

Update: Can you try changing Provider to like this. (and remove the state variable setPage and other definition line)

```
<AppContext.Provider value={{
       page: this.state.page, 
       setPage: page => this.setState({page})
 }}>
   {this.props.children}
</AppContext.Provider>
```

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo. However, after fixing it, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Shawn, Suspecting that state variable not carried correctly. Can you the updated answer?

Comment: I have added your codes and commented out state variables. But still. I am getting the same error.

Comment: Alright. After fixing the typo, the issue was not solved. So, I set breakpoints in `<AppContext.Provider value={{`and `</AppContext.Provider>`. After that, the issue got fixed automatically. I donn't get any error message.  I don't understand the reason behind it. But what I understand that it was basically a typo. So, I am choosing your answer as the correct one.